# How to have unlimited command-line arguments

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner of Java and am working on an assignment about discrete distribution.

First, I need a command-line argument "int m" as the number of the random indices.(which I do know how to do)
Then I need a series of command-line arguments of int a1,a2,…,an (which seems to be unlimited in number)

How do I create integers of these command-line arguments without limiting the total number in the sequence? Also, the assignment asks students not to create methods yet.

Sorry if it's a stupid question. Thank you for reading.

Comment: are you running the program using any editor/ide or from command line?

Comment: `main(String[] args)` ? How to convert string array to int array is already answered on SO

Comment: "not to create methods" where else should the code go? "I need ...  command-line arguments" do you mean you need to generate the arguments, or do you need to *read* the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for(int i = 1;i<args.length;i++){
        int randomIndex = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        //do whatever with randomIndex
    }
}
```

This loops over every command line argument except the first. The values are available inside the loop. If you need all values in an array, use the following instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] randomIndexes = new int[args.length-1];
    for(int i = 1;i<args.length;i++){
        randomIndexes[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);        
    }
}
```